# featuretools: why does dfs() do redundant calculation?

Tags: featuretools

Below is the example code from the official [docs](https://featuretools.alteryx.com/en/latest/getting_started/afe.html)

```
import featuretools as ft
es = ft.demo.load_mock_customer(return_entityset=True)

feature_matrix, feature_defs = ft.dfs(
    entityset=es,
    target_entity="customers",
    agg_primitives=["sum", "mode"],
    trans_primitives=["cum_max", "month", "cum_count"],
    max_depth=2
)

feature_defs

>> 
[<Feature: zip_code>,
 ....
 <Feature: MODE(sessions.device)>,
 <Feature: MODE(transactions.sessions.device)>,
 ...
 ]
```

After analyzing the calculation of `graph_feature()`, it looks like `MODE(sessions.device)` and `MODE(transactions.sessions.device)` are same even though they are calculated in different way. If I'm right, why does dfs calculate this redundantly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the question! While they look similar, these are actually different features. `MODE(sessions.device)` is the mode of devices over all sessions for a customer while `MODE(transactions.sessions.device)` is the mode of devices over all transactions for a customer.

As a quick example to demonstrate the difference, let's say a customer has 3 sessions:

```
session_id        device
------------------------
         A        Mobile
         B            PC              
         C            PC
```

There are also 5 transactions, each associated with one of these sessions:

```
transaction_id      session_id     sessions.device
--------------------------------------------------
             0               A              Mobile
             1               A              Mobile
             2               A              Mobile
             3               B                  PC
             4               C                  PC
```

In this case, the `MODE(sessions.device)` would be PC, but the `MODE(transactions.sessions.device)` would be Mobile because there's more transactions associated with Session A. In the feature graphs, the key difference is that `MODE(transactions.sessions.device)` first joins on the transactions entity. Even if you group by sessions, you won't end up with what you started with since each transaction now has it's own value.

Comment: Thanks! It really helps :)